# Getting a list of strings with only the first and last character from another list LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

From a given list of strings I need to use LINQ to generate a new sequence of strings, where each string consists of the first and last characters of the corresponding string in the original list.

Example:

```
stringList: new[] { "ehgrtthrehrehrehre", "fjjgoerugrjgrehg", "jgnjirgbrnigeheruwqqeughweirjewew" },
expected: new[] { "ee", "fg", "jw" });
```

```
list2 = stringList.Select(e => {e = "" + e[0] + e[e.Length - 1]; return e; }).ToList();
```

This is what I've tried, it works, but I need to use LINQ to solve the problem and I'm not sure how to adapt my solution.

Comment: You are already using [.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0), which is found in the Linq namespace. Perhaps you'll want to replace the `e => { ...; return e; }` part with an expression containing [`.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-7.0) and [`.Last()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: are you using already .NET 6 ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `"" + `? Why do you think it is okay to assign to `e` inside the lambda body? Why are you using a lambda body instead of an expression? Why did you name your lambda parameter `e`? What does that mean?

Comment: `var expected = stringList.Select(s => s.First() + s.Last()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for the sake of completeness here is a version using [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0)

```
var stringList = new string [] { "ehgrtthrehrehrehre", "fjjgoerugrjgrehg", "jgnjirgbrnigeheruwqqeughweirjewew" };
var result = stringList.Zip(stringList, (first, last) => $"{first.First()}{last.Last()}");
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment that Select is already part of LINQ, you can use this code.`var output = arr.Select(x => new string(new char[] { x.First(), x.Last() })).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var newList = stringList.Select(e => $"{e[0]}{e[e.Length - 1]}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach with LINQ and [`String.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove):

```
string[] input = new[] { "ehgrtthrehrehrehre", "fjjgoerugrjgrehg", "jgnjirgbrnigeheruwqqeughweirjewew" };
string[] result = input.Select(x => x.Remove(1, x.Length - 2)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return from p in stringList select p[0] + p[^1].ToString();
```